# Point-In-time-recovery in Greenplum Database

Tags: database-administration, greenplum, pitr

We have recently setup greenplum. Now the major concern is to setup strategy for PITR. Postgres provides PITR capability but I am a little confused as how will it work in greenplum as each segment will have it's own log directory and config file

Comment: Greenplum doesn't have PITR. If you have a segment failure, then the mirror process takes over which provides HA. If you want to recover a dropped object, you can restore it from the last backup. Remember that Greenplum is designed for analytics and data warehousing.

Comment: We are keeping historical/archived data in greenplum so there is a risk if any required segment gets corrupted and may need recovery upto some point

Comment: That is why Greenplum has mirroring and also why you schedule routine backups.

Answer (score 1):

We recently introduced the concept of named restore point to serve as a building block for PITR for greenplum. In order to use this you will need to use the catalog function gp_create_restore_point() which internally creates a cluster wide consistency point across all the segments. This function returns all the restore point location () for each segment and the master. Using these recovery points you will be able to configure the recover.conf in your PITR cluster

To demonstrate how Greenplum named restore points work, a new test
directory src/test/gpdb_pitr has been added. The test showcases WAL
Archiving in conjunction with the named restore points to do
Point-In-Time Recovery.

In case you are most interested in the details, please refer to the following two commits that discusses this functionality in detail https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/commit/47896cc89b4935199aa7d97043f2b7572a71042b

https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/commit/40e0fd9ce6c7da3921f0b12e55118320204f0f6d

Comment: Have you guys made any tutorial as POC of this utility which can be followed?